# Theme for specific requesting computer

Tags: theming

Similarly to changing the theme based on the requesting browser or logged in user, I want to change the theme based on where the request is coming from.

If a request comes from a specific address, domain or computer, how can I force a specific theme? I can't seem to find a module that accomplishes this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible with

- [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey)
- [ThemeKey Properties](http://drupal.org/project/themekey_properties)

Comment: That looks spot on... I'll don't think I saw that in any of my searches.

Answer (score 4):

You can also create your custom module and use [`hook_custom_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7)

And do your own detection in there.

Eg:

```
function YOURMODULE_custom_theme() {
  if (ip_address() == '192.168.5.212') {
    return 'THEME_NAME';
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm learning how to code modules atm, so I do value this answer... but ThemeKey works.